# create tight bounding box around textGrob in R

Tags: r

how can i create a tight bounding box around a textGrob object?

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
fg <- frameGrob()
fg <- packGrob(fg, textGrob("Hi there"))
grid.draw(fg)
```

adding another label

```
grid.newpage()
fg <- frameGrob()
tg <- textGrob(label = rep("Hi there",2),x = c(0.25,0.75),y=c(0.5,0.5))
rg <- rectGrob(x = tg$x, y = tg$y, width = grobWidth(tg) + unit(1,"mm"),                 
height = grobHeight(tg) + unit(2,"mm"))
fg <- packGrob(fg, rg)
fg <- packGrob(fg, tg)
```

Using `grid::xDetail` and `grid::yDetails` to locate hull of text (but works only on indiv grobTexts not on multiple labels

[image]

```
  tg_a <- textGrob(label = c("Hi there"),x = c(0.25),y=c(0.5),rot=0)
  tg_b <- textGrob(label = c('something very long'),x = c(0.4),y=c(0.5),rot=0)

  tg_list_in <- list(
    list(tg=tg_a,rot=0),
    list(tg=tg_b,rot=0),
    list(tg=tg_a,rot=45),
    list(tg=tg_b,rot=45),
    list(tg=tg_a,rot=90),
    list(tg=tg_b,rot=90)
    )

  tg_list <- lapply(tg_list_in,function(tgl){
    tg <- tgl$tg
    tg$rot <- tgl$rot
    data.frame(
      x=sapply(seq(0,270,90),function(x) convertUnit(grid::xDetails(tg,x),unitTo = 'native')),
      y=sapply(seq(0,270,90),function(x) convertUnit(grid::yDetails(tg,x),unitTo = 'native'))
    )  
  })

  min_dims <- apply(do.call('rbind',tg_list),2,min)
  max_dims <- apply(do.call('rbind',tg_list),2,max)

  op <- par(mfrow = c(3, 2))
  rots <- unlist(sapply(tg_list_in,'[',2))
  for(idx in 1:length(tg_list)){
  plot(c(min_dims[1], max_dims[1]), c(min_dims[2],max_dims[2]), type = "n",
       xlab='',ylab='',main=sprintf('%s : rotate %s',tg_list_in[[idx]]$tg$label,rots[idx]))
  polygon(tg_list[[idx]])
  }
  par(op)
```

Comment: Would adding a `rectGrob` work for you?

Comment: it covers it up and doesnt read from the width of the text

Answer (score 1):

Using the same setup as you are (with `packGrob` and `frameGrob`s) you could do:

```
grid.newpage()
fg <- frameGrob()
tg <- textGrob(label = rep("Hi there",2),x = c(0.25,0.75),y=c(0.5,0.5))
rg <- rectGrob(x = tg$x, y = tg$y, width = stringWidth(tg$label) + unit(1,"mm"),                 
               height = stringHeight(tg$label) + unit(2,"mm"))
fg <- packGrob(fg, rg)
fg <- packGrob(fg, tg)
grid.draw(fg)
```

[image]

Comment: cool. how do i generalize that to multiple labels in the `textGrob` object?

Comment: I updated original question with 2 labels and the solution above, the boxes are no longer tight

Comment: Ok, see my update. Use `stringWidth`/`stringHeight` instead

Comment: final question... (maybe)... how can i adjust that to make it sensitive to tg$rot?

Comment: would moving to `gridExtra::ngonGrob` be easier?

Comment: @yonicd probably. The reason its not working is that `rectGrob` doesn't know about the `viewport` of `textGrob`. I can get it to work for a single label in the `textGrob`, but if you want multiple labels like in your example it doesn't work. To incorporate the `viewport` into the height/width calculation you need to use `grobWidth/Height` rather than `stringWidth/Height`. `grobWidth/Height` would return one value for the whole text grob rather than several for each label

Comment: is there a way to split tg into seperate tg's for each label?

Comment: this is a similar question that you may know the quick ans to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513710/mapping-grid-draw-npc-scale-to-native